# Expressing the solutions of a DE as an implicit function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a second order linear ODE, I computed the solution as :

$x(t)=c_1e^{\lambda_1 t}+c_2e^{\lambda_2 t}+u$

where $u$ is a constant function and $\lambda_{1,2}$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial. I was not provided any initial conditions, so I can't solve for $c_1,c_2$.  Moreover,

$\dot{x}(t)=\lambda_1c_1e^{\lambda_1 t}+\lambda_2c_2e^{\lambda_2 t}$

Is it possible to express both $x,\dot{x}$ as an implicit function?

e.g. :  $x(t)-\dot{x}(t)=\frac{2u}{c_1-c_2}$

or something similar?

Comment: sorry but it's not very clear to me. What is $f_k$? And how do you compute it?

Comment: Oh alright then, many thanks.